# How do i save the most recent value of a variable in JS / JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I want to get the count of all the images on all the webpages that I visit, and keep adding the count to a totalCount variable which will be always available (Stored locally).

The code below counts all the images when I visit a page, using tampermonkey

```
var n = $('img[src]').length;
alert(count);
```

but the problem with the above code is that some pages load more images later on, which does not reflect in the count as it is fired only once per page. So I modified the code as shown below

```
var count=0;
var n

waitForKeyElements ('img[src]', actionFunction);

function actionFunction (jNode) {
    n = $('img[src]').length;
    if(count != n){
        count = n;
        alert(count);
    }

}
```

now the count variable will update as soon as more images are found on the page. My question is, how do I add this count to 'totalCount'?

I know this can be done using GM.Setvalue in tampermonkey. For this, i would need the most recent value of 'count' variable which can be added to totalCount when the page reloads or tab closes. But How do i get only the most recent value of count variable? I tried on Unload function but can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

As i see you should save value to local storage each time is is changes inside `actionFunction` then you will always have last value in storage.